# ExcuteQueryAsync functions inconvenient

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

Can any body explain this ?

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

it always output an Error in on MSDN site sure i've something wrong it worked when i replaced with the functions like

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender,args){...},function(sender,args){...});
```

can anybody tell why ? and whats "createDelegate" ? and whats "this" ?

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA9AE801B5328F18!1627&authkey=!APlXsyQQR9a-DJI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG the error

**Copied code from PastBin**

```
getAllFilesInFolders("galleroma")
function getAllFilesInFolders(listName) {
    var images = [];
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var collListItem;
    //SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

 var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
   // camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("/"+ListName+"/"+Folder);



collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(oList);
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(File, FileSystemObjectType)');

 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
       var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();                                                                                                                    
        if(currentItem.get_fileSystemObjectType() == "0")
        {
            var file = currentItem.get_file();
            if(file != null)
            {
                //console.log('File Name: ' + file.get_name() + '\n' + 'File Url: ' + file.get_serverRelativeUrl());
                images.push(file.get_serverRelativeUrl());

            }



        }

    }  

                    console.log(images);


    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Error getting list items: ' + args.get_message());
    }


}
```

it worked only like this

```
Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded)
```

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/75iRVfHz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has objects and functions.

`this` is attached to functions. When you invoke a function `this` get initialized differently based on how it is invoked.

Below code is the typical pattern used in MSDN

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function StartFunction()
{
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var listCollection = web.get_lists();
    ...
    clientContext.load(..);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  //show error message ()stacktrace
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    //show successful message
    alert('Done!');
}
</script>
```

`Function.createDelegate` creates a delegate function that retains the context first used during an objects creation. The `createDelegate` function is useful when setting up an event handler to point to an object method that must use the `this` pointer within its scope.

Comment: Amal good explanation. can you explain more, i still don't get it. and by the way good question.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to call `executeQueryAsync` in JSOM:

```
context.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, _onSucceed), 
Function.createDelegate(this, _onFail)
);
```

and

```
context.executeQueryAsync(_onSucceed, _onFail);
```

The difference between the two is

> the former allows you to override what the value of the "this" variable will be inside the function. In the latter case, not using Function.createDelegate, when you are inside either the _onSucceed or _onFail  callbacks, this will reference the callback function itself – onSucceed or onFail  respectively.

For more details visit [this link](http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=353) from where I copied the above information. But basically creating delegate sets the value of `this` in callback functions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Garima for the link and the explaination it was helpful

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: Just want to add that Function.createDelegate more or less just do an .apply() , you could have done context.executeQueryAsync(_onSucceed.apply(this),....);

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the explanation given by Amal, the reason you see error is `var collListItem;` is defined in `getAllFilesInFolders` function and the `onQuerySucceeded` method doesn't have its information unless you use `this.collListItem` which is passed during `Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded)`. Else you should define `var collListItem;` globally in order to use it as you are doing correctly.

**UPDATE**

If you were to use `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);`, then the variable `collListItem` will need to be declared globally as `onQuerySucceeded` doen't have any context about it. Also using `this.collListItem` will not be helpful as `this` doesn't represent the function `getAllFilesInFolders` where `collListItem` is declared. 
However, when you use

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

In the `onQuerySucceeded`, you can use `this.collListItem` as `this` now represents `getAllFilesInFolders` object which is passed as the first parameter in  `Function.createDelegate`

Comment: when i defined collListItem  variable Globally Still the same error 
only worked when i remove this.onQuerySucceed to be come
Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded)

Comment: If you use `Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded)` then you don't need to declare the variable globally. `this` makes it possible to refer to variable using `this.variable` in `onQuerySucceeded` method.

Comment: sorry Nadeem u know i just started looking at that yesterday im little bit confused can u give little example of what u just said ?

Comment: Not a problem. We are here to help each other.